# CakePHP getLastInsertId() returns zero

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.5

I am fairly new to CakePHP and having a problem getting last inserted id. My schema is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `markets` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `region_code` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `country_code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `language` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `default_language` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `markets`
   ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   ADD UNIQUE KEY `region_code` (`region_code`),
   ADD KEY `locale` (`country_code`),
   ADD KEY `language` (`language`);

ALTER TABLE `markets`
   MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=8;
```

And this is my logic:

```
$this->loadModel('Market');
if( isset($this->request->data['Market']) ) {
  $this->Market->set($this->request->data);
  if( $this->Market->validates() ) {
    $this->Market->save($this->request->data);
    echo $this->Market->id; //displays zero
    echo $this->Market->getLastInsertID(); //also displays zero
  }
}
```

It all looks good in MySQL though, as id gets auto incremented there as it's supposed to be.

P.S. I just inserted another record and here's what's returned:

```
array (size=1)
  'Market' => 
    array (size=8)
      'name' => string 'Japan' (length=5)
      'region_code' => string 'JP' (length=2)
      'country_code' => string 'JP' (length=2)
      'language' => string 'ja_JP' (length=5)
      'default_language' => string 'ja_JP' (length=5)
      'modified' => string '2015-04-23 09:11:34' (length=19)
      'created' => string '2015-04-23 09:11:34' (length=19)
      'id' => string '0' (length=1)
```

[image: Here's the saved data in phpMyAdmin]

Ok, so for now I just added a function called 'getMarketLastInsertId' to the Market model, which takes 'country_code' (unique key in the table) as a parameter and returns the last id...
Thanks

Comment: you could try $this->ModelName->getInsertID();

Comment: $this->Market->getInsertId(); returns zero as well

Comment: Have you properly constructed the array to save to the database? You are not checking that the save completes sucessfully

Comment: $result = $this->Market->save($this->request->data); $record_id=$result->id;

Comment: are you sure you are saving anything to the database? Why not doing if($this->Market->save($this->request->data)) { // print stuff }

Comment: Yes, I am sure it's saving correctly. As I said in my original post, "it all looks good in MySQL though, as id gets auto incremented there as it's supposed to be."

Comment: @petermk does data saved successfully to Database otherwise you won't get returned id?

Comment: Yes, it's being saved correctly. Then, when I do an edit, getLastInsertId() returns the correct id saved in the DB. It's new records that always return zero.

Comment: before the `$this->Market->save($this->request->data);` add this call `$this->Market->create();` that should set the `$this->Market->id` var to the new id to be inserted

Comment: That did not work either, still getting zero.

Comment: Are you setting any value to id _before_ saving the data? by the way, if you use `$this->Market->set($this->request->data)`, you don't need to pass data again to `save()`

Comment: I have a form field echo $this->Form->input('id', array('type' => 'hidden', 'class' => 'mediuminput')); but I never set its value anywhere in my code. Your suggestion returned zero as well.

Answer (score 2):

In the create table statement you have shown

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
```

should actually be

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

for `id` to be an auto increment field. So I doubt your claims about the field getting filled with auto increment values.

Comment: Hm, I've been using MySQL for over 10 years and know how to use phpMyAdmin as well. The values are being saved and auto incremented. Thank you.

Comment: @petermk Even experienced users can make a mistake. ADmad is right, this schema will not auto increment. See the proof here: http://i.imgur.com/cE8dzEP.png

Comment: The schema above was a phpmyadmin export and I forgot to include ALTER TABLE statements from the bottom of the exported file. Sorry about that.

Comment: Over 10 years of experience still doesn't prevent simple human errors ;)

Comment: The database works as it should, so there was no error on my part.

Answer (score 1):

In CakePHP 3.X.X you can do like this

```
$result = $this->Market->save($this->request->data);
$record_id=$result->id;
```

More general

```
$result=$this->ModelName->save($whatever);
$record_id=$result->id;
```

For More Info

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#a-glance-over-saving-data
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-entities

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not 3.0. It's 2.5.4

Comment: @petermk i have pasted links from official 3.0 guide. hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You don't have you primary key set up correctly. You should have NOT NULL and AUTO_INCREMENT applied to your id column as well has having it defined as you primary key.

Comment: You missed this: ALTER TABLE `markets`
   MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=8;